# can you create multiplayer game on ios without enabling game center

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer

I am trying to understand to what extent the games that have game center enabled are multiplayer games. Please help me understand following questions:

a) Is it possible to create a multi-player game without enabling game-center
b) Can a game with game-center enabled be a single-player game.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a multi-player game without enabling game-center?

It is definitely possible, but harder to spin up. Without GameCenter, you need to create your own servers, store game sessions, handle game data being transferred from player to player, and other non-trivial things. GameCenter basically says “Don’t worry about all that network and infrastructure, we got it covered. All you need to do is use our framework.”

> Can a game with game-center enabled be a single-player game?

Also a yes! You can actually build a game without GameCenter and let you app handle everything. GameCenter is useful here when you want to add a leaderboard, let players compete with other players, enable high scores, etc.